# SQL Server : calculating ages in stored procedure returns conversion failed

Tags: sql-server, stored-procedures

I wrote a stored procedure for calculating ages from values in table columns.

This is that stored procedure:

```
WITH ages AS
(
    SELECT 
        DATEDIFF(YEAR, CONVERT(datetime, pf.Value, 104), pf.CreatedOn) END as Age
    FROM 
        Fields pf
    WHERE
        pf.Value IS NOT NULL
)
SELECT  
    (SELECT COUNT(Age) 
     FROM ages 
     WHERE ages.Age > 17 AND ages.Age < 25) AS '18-24',
    (SELECT COUNT(Age) 
     FROM ages 
     WHERE ages.Age > 24 AND ages.Age < 31) AS 25-30',
    (SELECT COUNT(Age) 
     FROM ages 
     WHERE ages.Age > 30 AND ages.Age < 36) AS '31-35',
    (SELECT COUNT(Age) 
     FROM ages 
     WHERE ages.Age > 35) AS '> 35'
```

In this column (Value), birthdays are stored as string value in format like this: 02.10.1987 00:00:00 (DD.MM.YYY HH:mm:ss).

In this `Fields` table I have 3500 rows.

Data looks like this:

```
02.10.1987 00:00:00
29.07.1967 12:33:11
02.10.1987 00:00:00
15.11.1959 00:00:00
07.11.1975 00:00:00
```

When I run procedure like that, SQL server return following error:

> Conversion failed when converting date and/or time from character string

Procedure is executed normally, if I put Top 100000 in the stored procedure, like this:

```
WITH ages AS
(
SELECT TOP 100000 datediff(year, CONVERT(datetime, pf.Value, 104), pf.CreatedOn)
       END as Age
FROM Fields pf
where pf.Value is not null
)
SELECT  (select count(Age) FROM ages where ages.Age>17 and ages.Age<25) as '18-24',
        (select count(Age) FROM ages where ages.Age>24 and ages.Age<31)  as '25-30',
        (select count(Age) FROM ages where ages.Age>30 and ages.Age<36)  as '31-35',        
        (select count(Age) FROM ages where ages.Age>35)  as '>35'
```

And as I wrote, I have only 3500 rows.

All my data are formatted correct and stored procedure is getting all not null values.

Does someone know why this is happening? Why it is working with Top inserted, but not without it?

Is it something with memory allocation what SQL Server do?

Answer (score 0):

These are all long shots but maybe try:

- Rebuild all indexes on the table
- Run EXEC sp_recompile N'Fields';

It's entirely possible the TOP 10000 & straight SELECT are producing different execution plans but I still don't see why that would affect the data.

Are you sure there isn't something else going on? Both connections for the queries are use the same user? regional settings for both connections are the same?

Answer (score 0):

Try changing CONVERT(datetime, pf.Value, 104) to Cast(pf.Value as DateTime) or 
Cast(pf.Value as Date) if you don't really care about the timestamp portion of the date.

Also, if pf.CreatedOn is of type varchar do the same thing with it.

```
    WITH ages AS
(
    SELECT 
        DATEDIFF(YEAR, cast(pf.Value AS DateTime), CAST(pf.CreatedOn AS DATETIME)) END as Age
    FROM 
        Fields pf
    WHERE
        pf.Value IS NOT NULL
)
```

AH Sorry... I didn't realize your dates were in "you're not from around here are you?" format.  Try this less attractive looking solution.

```
--TestData
 DECLARE @x NVARCHAR(MAX) = '29.11.1956 00:00:00'
 DECLARE @x NVARCHAR(MAX) = '2.1.1956 00:00:00'

--Solution
 select    
 -- Monthpart dd.mm.yyy
 SUBSTRING(@x, 
    CHARINDEX('.', @x) + 1 ,
        CHARINDEX('.',@x,CHARINDEX('.', @x) + 1 )-  CHARINDEX('.', @x)  -1) + '/' 
 --DayPart dd.mm.yyy
  + SUBSTRING(@x, 1, CHARINDEX('.', @X) - 1)  + '/'
 --YearPart   
  + RIGHT(LEFT (@x, CHARINDEX(' ',@x) -1),4)
```

Comment: When I implement your proposal, i get following error: The conversion of a nvarchar data type to a datetime data type resulted in an out-of-range value. It happens on value '29.11.1956 00:00:00' in database. This is 20th record in table. So for top 19 it is working, but for all, not :(

Comment: Sorry I assumed dates were in mmddyyyy like format.